# Transform Python dictionary into List

Tags: python, json, algorithm, sorting, python-3.6

With Python 3.6, what's the most efficient way to transform this dictionary into a List?
I've tried to use a lot of loops, but it doesn't look efficient at all, it takes some time.
This is the original dictionary:

```py
d = {'Owner': [{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAAA@gmail.com'},
               {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBBB@gmail.com'},
               {'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com'}],
     'Stakeholder': [{'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com'},
                     {'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAA@gmail.com'}],
     'Team': [{'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com'},
              {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBB@gmail.com'}]}
```

This is the goal:

```py
[{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAAA@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Stakeholder']},
 {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBBB@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Stakeholder']}]
```

Thanks!

Edit 1:
So far I could get a list of unique users:

```
list_users = []

for role, users in old_dict.items():
    for user in users:
        list_users.append(user)

unique_list_of_users = []
for i in range(len(list_users)):
    if list_users[i] not in list_users[i + 1:]:
        unique_list_of_users.append(list_users[i])

for user in unique_list_of_users:
    user["role"] = []
```

Comment: If you've tried loops, you should add them to your question we SO can see what you've tried.

Comment: I've added some code that I have now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
output = []
for k, v in d.items():
    for dct in v:
        for x in output:
            if x['login'] == dct['login']:
                x['roles'].append(k)
                break
        else:
            output.append({**dct, **{'roles': [k]}})
print(output)
```

Output:

```py
[{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAAA@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Stakeholder']},
 {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBBB@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Stakeholder']}]
```

Note: you specified you were on Python 3.6, so `{**dct, **{'roles': [k]}}` will work for you. It will not work on Python 3.4 or lower. If you are on 3.4 or lower, use:

```py
dct.update({'roles': [k]})
output.append(dct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a key in the `login` and `mail` field, you can use those to quickly build a dictionnary with the values you need and then access them.

```py
d = {
    "Owner": [
        {"login": "AAAA", "mail": "AAAAA@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "BBBB", "mail": "BBBBB@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "CCCC", "mail": "CCCC@gmail.com"},
    ],
    "Stakeholder": [
        {"login": "DDDD", "mail": "DDDD@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "AAAA", "mail": "AAAA@gmail.com"},
    ],
    "Team": [
        {"login": "CCCC", "mail": "CCCC@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "BBBB", "mail": "BBBB@gmail.com"},
    ],
}

tmp = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    for dd in v:
        try:
            tmp[dd["login"]]["roles"].append(k)
        except KeyError:
            tmp[dd["login"]] = dd
            tmp[dd["login"]].update({"roles": [k]})   

list(tmp.values())
```

gives

```py
[{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAAA@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Stakeholder']},
 {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBBB@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Stakeholder']}]
```

Comment: Your current code doesn't produce what you give as the result (I upvoted before noticing this).

Comment: @DarrylG good catch, I had not copy/pasted the change for asking permission to asking forgiveness, now I have and it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
import pprint
 
d = {
    "Owner": [
        {"login": "AAAA", "mail": "AAAAA@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "BBBB", "mail": "BBBBB@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "CCCC", "mail": "CCCC@gmail.com"},
    ],
    "Stakeholder": [
        {"login": "DDDD", "mail": "DDDD@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "AAAA", "mail": "AAAA@gmail.com"},
    ],
    "Team": [
        {"login": "CCCC", "mail": "CCCC@gmail.com"},
        {"login": "BBBB", "mail": "BBBB@gmail.com"},
    ],
}

res = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in d.items():
    for obj in d[k]:
        if not obj['login'] in res:
            res[obj['login']].update(obj)
        res[obj['login']].setdefault('roles', []).append(k)

pprint.pprint(list(res.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAAA@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Stakeholder']},
 {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBBB@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']},
 {'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Stakeholder']}]
```

Comment: One caveat though - this produces final output with the "last" `mail` key - the OP's expected output wants the "first" `mail` key

Comment: @Mortz What do you mean? Not sure I understand

Comment: For `login: AAAA` the expected output for `mail` is `mail: AAAAA@gmail.com` (5 As) - which comes from `Owner` - whereas your output is `mail: AAAA@gmail.com` (4 As) - which comes from `Stakeholder`

Comment: @Mortz Nice catch! I've fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `itertools` -

```py
from itertools import chain, groupby
flattened_items = sorted(chain.from_iterable([list(zip([k]*len(v), v)) for item in d.items() for k, v in (item,)]), key=lambda x: x[1]['login'])

for k, v in groupby(flattened_items, key=lambda x: x[1]['login']):
    all_roles, all_dicts = zip(*v)
    new_dict = {kk: vv for d in reversed(all_dicts) for kk, vv in d.items()}
    new_dict['roles'] = list(all_roles)
    print(new_dict)
```

What I am doing is to flatten the `d.items()` into `(key, value)` pairs, sort it by the values and then aggregate using `itertools.groupby`

**Output**

```
{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAAA@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Stakeholder']}
{'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBBB@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']}
{'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']}
{'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Stakeholder']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most optimal way is to let your dicts that belong to the list of each role hashable. Then, you can make them be the key of another dict that will tell the roles of each login+mail dict. The python code would be:

```
class Hashabledict(dict):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(frozenset(self))


def solve(d):
    roles = dict()

    for key, value in d.items():
        for cur_dict in value:
            hashable_cur_dict = Hashabledict(cur_dict)

            if hashable_cur_dict not in roles:
                roles[hashable_cur_dict] = {key}
            else:
                roles[hashable_cur_dict].add(key)

    answer = list()

    for key, value in roles.items():
        key['roles'] = list(value)
        answer.append(key)

    return answer
```

An example of use is below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {'Owner': [{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAA@gmail.com'},
                   {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBB@gmail.com'},
                   {'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com'}],
         'Stakeholder': [{'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com'},
                         {'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAA@gmail.com'}],
         'Team': [{'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com'},
                  {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBB@gmail.com'}]}

    test = solve(d)
    print(test)
```

The output is:

```
[{'login': 'AAAA', 'mail': 'AAAA@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Stakeholder']}, {'login': 'BBBB', 'mail': 'BBBB@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']}, {'login': 'CCCC', 'mail': 'CCCC@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Owner', 'Team']}, {'login': 'DDDD', 'mail': 'DDDD@gmail.com', 'roles': ['Stakeholder']}]
```